# ajax gzip compress a string for postdata

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, gzip

Can't seem to find anything related to gzip compressing a string.  Only find broken sites or suggestions for compressions that won't work as gzip.  Also lots of talk of server side implementation.  However I wish to send the encoded data from the client.

To give clarification all my clients use greasemonkey or scriptish and all my clients are generally on some version of a recent Firefox or one of it's derivatives, so content encoding for everyone is not an issue.

What I do need is a pure javascript or some sort of library loadable by javascript to gzip compress a string.

Answer (score 2):

Just achieved this using https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate However the postdata for whatever reason will strip the + signs and replace them with spaces.

To send the data via javascript:

```
params.mapdata= btoa(RawDeflate.deflate(JSON.stringify(mapdata)));
```

To receive the data via php:

```
$value = gzinflate(base64_decode(preg_replace('/\s/', '+',$value)));
```