# How to compact JSON data

Tags: json, jquery

I have large JSON data travelling over the network via Ajax calls. This needs to be compacted. A typical entry in the data has very large name like DesignatedPowerOfAttorneyLastName e.g.

```
{"DesignatedPowerOfAttorneyLastName":"Joe","DesignatedPowerOfAttorneyFirstName":"Smith"}
```

This results in a javascript error on some browsers
Stop running this script ?
*A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive*

My question is if I replace these variable names with much shorter names such i, j, k etc. can I gain advantage in network bandwidth? I don't want to use RJSON type of technology to compact the data?

Is there a way to estimate how much bandwidth advantage can be gained in a particular JSON string without actually making change to code. Any tools related to this please add your comments.

Comment: You'd need to avoid collisions; it's probably easier and safer to use a compression algorithm.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862166/ajax-gzip-compress-a-string-for-postdata

Comment: Would you get an advantage in network bandwidth? yes. does that make it a good idea? no. (readability, maintainability, collisions etc).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is it possible to reduce the data packet size by changing the variable name inside the Json object since it looks like there is more amount consumed by the name than data itself.

Comment: @Oren please advise on how to measure the estimate of improvement in bandwidth.

Comment: That is invalid JSON.